# Website is not following Cloudflare's Pagerules

Tags: cache, cloudflare

I'm using Cloudflare's Page Rules to cache absolutely everything on my site (except ajax.php) for at least 5 days (images, css, js are cached 30 days).

[image: Cloudflare Page Rules]

Although all web content is set to be cached for 5 days, whenever I test it, first I get of course a Cloudflare MISS status, and afterwards I get Cloudflare HIT statuses but the **expires** response header only seems to be set 1 hour in the future.

[image: Console]

Why is the site's cache not following the page rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. `Cache-Control: max-age=...` header takes priority over `Expires` header for HTTP/1.1 clients. See [MDN's Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires).

Quoting from [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3):

> If a response includes both an Expires header and a max-age directive, the max-age directive overrides the Expires header, even if the Expires header is more restrictive

Furthermore, Cloudflare will [only modify `Expires` *or* `Cache-Control` if](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168276-Understanding-Browser-Cache-TTL):

- The value of the `Cache-Control` header from the origin web server is less than the **Browser Cache TTL** Cloudflare setting, or
- the origin web server does not send a `Cache-Control` or an `Expires` header.

It is possible that your webserver sends different `Cache-Control` and `Expires` header values in the first place.

Comment: makes sense. The [bandwidth usage](https://imgur.com/a/SZHBVVw) shows the amount of uncached bandwidth usage, which should really be a minority, not the majority. I checked and I have no Cache-Control nor Expires settings on my Apache server httpd.conf

Comment: There's a lot of cause why your Uncached to Cached bandwidh ratio is bad. See [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-Cloudflare-cache-for-static-content-) and [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/understanding-uncached-requests/11229/2) for more info. Use [Redbot](https://redbot.org/) to see how effective your caching is. And, PHP frameworks and libraries can also send its own `Cache-Control` and `Expires` header.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=432000"` for specific FilesMatch and it seems to be working now.